# How do I make a lucky spin with a list of sprites in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

So I'm basically trying to make a function that takes in a list of sprites, goes through them, putting them as the sprite of the spriterenderer component really fast, say switch 30 times in the first second, this switching speed is to slow down over a period of say 7 seconds, at the end of which the speed of change is about 1 sprite per second, and then the function stops.

I've tried using coroutine, but they seem to ignore the value of a float that I increase after every switch and use with Yield return new WaitForSeconds.

Any other clue on how it can be achieved?

Can't seem to get the rate of change organically slow down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `yield` the coroutine in the `for loop` starting with your initial rate of change and changing the rate as we lerp through each and every sprite.

Here is the code for that..

```
public class SpriteSwitch : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Sprite> Sprites;
    public float StartingRateOfChange = 30f;
    
    private SpriteRenderer _spriteRenderer;
    private Coroutine _switchSprites;
    
    private void Start()
    {
        _spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        
        if (Sprites != null && Sprites.Count > 0)
            SwitchSprites(Sprites);
    }

    public void SwitchSprites(List<Sprite> sprites)
    {
        if (_switchSprites != null)
            StopCoroutine(_switchSprites);

        _switchSprites = StartCoroutine(StartSpriteSwitching(sprites));
    }

    private IEnumerator StartSpriteSwitching(List<Sprite> sprites)
    {
        var spriteCount = sprites.Count;
        var startSwitchInterval = 1f / StartingRateOfChange;
        var currentSwitchInterval = startSwitchInterval;
        
        // loop through all the sprites
        for (var i = 0; i < spriteCount; i++)
        {
            _spriteRenderer.sprite = sprites[i];
            
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(currentSwitchInterval);

            // changing switch interval by lerping through every sprite
            currentSwitchInterval = i < spriteCount
                ? Mathf.Lerp(startSwitchInterval, 1f, (float)i / spriteCount)
                : 0f;
        }

        _switchSprites = null;
    }
}
```